# How to filter a collection in thymeleaf th:each using another property in comparison

Tags: html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-el

I am trying to filter the collection using Thymeleaf by following the example in the following url.
"Projection & selection on collection" section.
http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/spring-mvc-part-iv-thymeleaf-advanced-usage/

```
<tr th:each="artist,rowStat : ${listArtits.?[alive == true]}">
...
</tr>
```

However I would like to use another property instead of fixed value (true/false). For example

```
<tr th:each="artist,rowStat : ${listArtits.?[played > playedCountReq]}">
...
</tr>
```

where as playedCountReq is another form variable available to Thymeleaf. I get the following error. Property or field 'playedCountReq' cannot be found on object of type ...

I tried multiple ways but no success. Any suggestions?

Comment: The only work around/solution I found so far is to use th:block. Move the th:each in th:block and th:if in the tr tag

Comment: please put in the code for your whole form/table that way we can see the full picture

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I succeded :) Here is solution:

in controller:

```
(...)
Person p1 = new Person();
p1.setAge(20);
Person p2 = new Person();
p2.setAge(30);
List<Person> list = Lists.newArrayList(p1,p2);
modelMap.addAttribute("list", list);
Integer minAge = 13;
modelMap.addAttribute("minAge", minAge);
(...)
```

in html:

```
<table th:with="min=${minAge}">
<tr th:each="person,rowStat : ${list.?[age > __${min}__]}">
<td><span th:text="${person.age}"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Output:

```
30
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 6):

Within the selection filter, unqualified properties are relative to the element of the collection being filtered. But, the variable `#root` is always defined to be the root context object. This is how you can refer to variables at the root level from within the selection filter.

```
<tr th:each="artist,rowStat : ${listArtists.?[played gt #root.playedCountReq]}">
…
</tr>
```

Refer to "[The #this and #root variables](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-this-root)" section in the Spring EL documentation for more information.