# ThymeLeaf selection a specific enum type

Tags: java, html, css, enums, thymeleaf

```js
package com.newconstructs.controller.home;

import com.newconstructs.domain.Animal;
import com.newconstructs.domain.api.Layout;
import com.newconstructs.service.api.AnimalService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


@Controller
public class HomeController {
  @Inject
  private AnimalService animalService;
  
  @Layout(
    title = "",
    description = "",
    selectedNav = "all"
  )
  @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/home"})
  public String init(ModelMap modelMap) {
    List<Animal> animals = animalService.findAll();
    
    modelMap.put("animals", animals);
    
    return "home";
  }
}


package com.newconstructs.service;

import com.newconstructs.domain.Animal;
import com.newconstructs.domain.Animal.AnimalType;
import com.newconstructs.service.api.AnimalService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.*;


@Service
public class AnimalServiceImpl implements AnimalService {
  private static final List<Animal> ANIMALS;

  static {
    ANIMALS = new ArrayList<>();

    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.DOG, "Spot", 10, 7, 17, 0));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.DOG, "Rover", 15, 5, 2, 6));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.DOG, "Fido", 8, 6, 12, 15));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.CAT, "Mittens", 18, 3, 3, 0));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.CAT, "Snowball", 5, 0, 14, 1));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.CAT, "Waffles", 8, 11, 2, 18));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.SNAKE, "Slider", 6, 16, 14, 3));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.SNAKE, "Milton", 16, 6, 11, 17));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.SNAKE, "Spike", 6, 18, 2, 5));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.SNAKE, "Alice", 9, 11, 4, 6));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.RABBIT, "Flopsy", 14, 0, 12, 2));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.RABBIT, "Peter", 18, 18, 14, 3));
    ANIMALS.add(new Animal(AnimalType.RABBIT, "Oreo", 7, 4, 9, 1));
  }

  @Override
  public List<Animal> findAll() {

    return ANIMALS;
  }
}


package com.newconstructs.service.api;

import com.newconstructs.domain.Animal;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


@Validated
public interface AnimalService {
  public List<Animal> findAll();
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}


#content, #header, #footer {
  width: 600px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
}

.menu > a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}

.menu > a.selected {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.menu > a:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}

.menu > a:focus, .menu > a:hover {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

h2.header {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}


.animal-list {
  width: 400px;
}


.animal {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 4px 5px;
}


.name {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.characteristic {
  text-align: right;
}

.type {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  float: right;
}

.rating-table, .rating-table th, .rating-table td, .stats-table, .stats-table th, .stats-table td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 4.0rem;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h2 class="header">All Animals</h2>
  <div class="animal-list">
    <div class="animal" th:each="animal : ${animals}">
      <span class="name" th:text="${animal.name}">Name</span>
      <span class="type" th:text="${animal.animalType}">Animal Type</span>
      <span class="offense" th:text="${animal.offense}">Offense</span>
      <span class="defense" th:text="${animal.defense}">Defense</span>
      <span class="health" th:text="${animal.health}">Health</span>
      <span class="items" th:text="${animal.items}">Items</span>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to only get specific enum types from a Java array. If the code below shows me all animals in the list ANIMALS. How can I alter it show only enum type DOG. I have created a Plunker to show all my code. https://embed.plnkr.co/exdZ7Uw2jraxpac8Zrlb/

Basically, I need to alter the code below to get only dogs, cats, etc.

```
<div class="animal" th:each="animal : ${animals}">
```

Comment: Load the ones you need.

Comment: How? I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: You should put the relevant code here and I'll look at what you're doing.

Comment: probably something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476393/how-to-filter-a-collection-in-thymeleaf-theach-using-another-property-in-compar

Answer (score 1):

This can be done a number of ways but I would add a method to the service, call it `getAllByAnimalType(AnimalType type)`, and give yourself the flexibility to let the view (html) show whatever animal(s) you throw at it while not passing unneeded data.

Since the data gets loaded in the view model you'll provide a way to know what the user wants through the url(s). Maybe:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/dogs"})
public String dogs(ModelMap modelMap) {
    List<Animal> animals = getAnimals(AnimalType.DOG);
    modelMap.put("animals", animals);    
    return "home";
}
...
private List<Animal> getAnimals(AnimalType type) {
    return animalService.findAllByAnimalType(type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use th:if to display only the  enum type DOG.

```
    <div id="content">
  <h2 class="header">All Animals</h2>
  <div class="animal-list">
    <div class="animal" th:each="animal : ${animals}">
    <th:block th:if="${#strings.toString(animal.animalType)== 'DOG'}">
      <span class="name" th:text="${animal.name}">Name</span>
      <span class="type" th:text="${animal.animalType}">Animal Type</span>
      <span class="offense" th:text="${animal.offense}">Offense</span>
      <span class="defense" th:text="${animal.defense}">Defense</span>
      <span class="health" th:text="${animal.health}">Health</span>
      <span class="items" th:text="${animal.items}">Items</span>
    </th:block>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```